# Conditional dependencies based on command line arguments

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

Not sure if this is a VSCode Java extension issue or not. We're trying to have conditional dependencies included depending on a specific Spring Boot profile we're passing in as a command line argument. It seems that when conditions are statically analysable, the Java language server is able to correctly provide intellisense, but when they are not, it fails. Here's an example, where when we use true/false, intellisense works, but when we use the commented out lines, it doesn't. I imagine this is the expected behaviour, and it still compiles fine, I'm just wondering if there's a way around making it work.

```java
def profiles = (project.hasProperty('profiles')
  ? project.property('profiles')
  : "local,https").split(",")

dependencies {
  // if (profiles.contains("local") && !profiles.contains("tc")) {
  if (false) {
    runtimeOnly "com.h2database:h2"
  }

  else {
    implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:$DB_DRIVER_VERSION"

    // if (profiles.contains("tc")) {
    if (true) {
      implementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:$TESTCONTAINERS_VERSION"
      runtimeOnly "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:$TESTCONTAINERS_VERSION"
      testCompile "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:$TESTCONTAINERS_VERSION"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an example of what happens in a test file

```java
// this import fails with intellisense, since the dependency is
// not included when using conditional dependencies based on CLI arguments
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

@Profile("tc")
// @Testcontainers
public class SampleIntegrationTest {
```

I should reiterate though, that this isn't a problem during normal build/run, it's just intellisense that doesn't work very well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that you aren't getting autocomplete and other features in VS Code, is that correct?

Comment: *"Spring Boot profile we're passing in as a command line argument"* Spring Boot profiles are a feature of a String Boot application, i.e. it is something you use at run-time, not it build time. As such, the Gradle build script, which is what I believe we're looking at, should not / cannot be based on a Spring Boot profile. Re-think what you're doing and whether this is a build/deployment option or a runtime option.

Comment: @Andreas I would say this is both runtime and build time. If I'm running a given profile during runtime, I need to ensure that the dependencies for that profile were included during build. For example, during bootRun with h2, there's no need to include other database drivers in the archive. The other solution is just to include everything at build time so that whichever profile I run has whatever it needs, but that seems like bloat, so seeing if something else is possible. But I'm open to other approaches!

Comment: @Code-Apprentice exactly, but only for the dependencies that are in conditional branches that are false. This makes sense of course, since if they're excluded based on static analysis then they shouldn't resolve in intellisense. It's just whether I can convice intellisense to give them to me anyways for the files that would be included based on command line arguments

Comment: When I type `if(p`, there's `profiles` shown and after `profiles.`, `contains` will also displayed in the list for me to choose. This is how intellisense works for me, do you mean this?

Comment: @MollyWang no that's from within the Gradle file. I included an edit on the question where I show where intellisense if failing.